# Generate RSA Keys Perform KeyPairGenerator x509

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to do the equivalent of the following commands, but in Java:

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 1024
openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -x509 -key privatekey.pem -out publickey.cer -days 365 
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in privatekey.pem -out privatekey.pcks8
```

I have the following code, which I understand generates both keys in pcks8 format, but how do I get the public key output in the same format as above? What else am I missing?

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = null;
try {
  keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
String privateKey = Base64.encodeBase64String(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
String publicKey = Base64.encodeBase64String(pair.getPublic().getEncoded());
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is the first time I've worked with asymmetric keys.

Comment: That 'format' you refer to is a self-signed X.509 certificate. Java can't generate that without using a third party library, for example the bouncycastle library.